# How do I animate shape keys within an action in Blender?

Tags: shape-keys, actions

I am animating an action for a character I have made in Blender, and I have created mouth shape keys for lip-syncing. I want this action to have the character lip-syncing to some audio and have some body language, but I can't animate shape keys in the action editor (I can't create keyframes with the shape keys). Am I missing something here? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to animate the shape keys you can change the view from Action Editor to "Shape Key Editor" or "Dope Sheet" editor.

[image: Shape Key Editor]

[image: Dopesheet]

Comment: Thank you :D One more question. Since I am editing the shape keys in a separate action, am I able to merge that with an action in the action editor?

Comment: Some time ago I tried to do that, but I couldn't find a way, apparently the shape key action and the actions are saved separately.

Comment: @BryanDean Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).